# How to use CSS sprite without a border in image

Tags: css, sprite

I am trying to use sprite image to optimise my website.

I uses png format for my image, and the image is like this:

[image]

My code css is like this:

```css
.bg-upperbar_1 {
    width: 55px; height: 55px;
    background: url('../../assets/img/home/spritesheet.png') -10px -10px;
}
```

My html is like this:

```html
<a class="home-upperbar home-top" href="<?php echo site_url('products/collection_watches'); ?>">
<img class="bg-upperbar_1">
</a>
```

But when I try to load my page, I'm getting a border for the picture even though the picture is png, like this:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Misdan, do you have a url where we can inspect it? I think It's just a border around the image

Comment: Is the image in an <a>?

Comment: @MrLister yes in <a> tag

Comment: @Misdan `border:0;` is enough to remove border, Add in styles

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a border is because your `<img>` doesn't have a `src` attribute set. If you want to use a sprite sheet as a background image, then you have to attach it to the `<a>` tag.

```css
.bg-upperbar_1 {
    width: 43px;
    height: 45px;
    background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) -47px -42px;
}

a{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<a class="home-upperbar home-top bg-upperbar_1" href="<?php echo site_url('products/collection_watches'); ?>">
</a>
```